# c++ linked list data checking

Tags: c++, linked-list

So I'm writing a Linked List class using templates and a nested node class. I have to lists and `int` list and a `string` list when I create an int node, it will still add to the string list if I add to it. I'm just curious on how to check the data to make sure that it is the same type as the data type of the current linked list.

If you need code I can add it, I'm just not sure which code you would need.

add first:

```
void addFirst(T data){
    if(this->size == 0)
        this->head = new Node(data);
    else{
        Node *newNode = new Node(data);
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }
    this->size++;
}; //add to the beginning of the list
```

Node:

```
class Node{
public:
    T data;
    Node* next;

    Node() {};
    Node(T data) {this->data = data; this->next = NULL;};
    void setData(T data) {this->data = data;};
    void setNext(Node* next) {this->next = next;};
    Node getNext() {return next;};
    T getData() {return data;};
};
```

add with index:

```
void add(int index) { //add at index
    T data;
    std::cout << "Enter your data: ";
    std::cin >> data;

    try{
        if(index < 0 || index > this->size){
            throw std::out_of_range("please choose a valid range");
        }
        if(index == 0){
            addFirst(data);
        }
        else{
            Node *newNode = new Node(data);
            Node *prev, *curr = this->head;
            for(int i = 0; i < index; i++){
                prev = curr;
                curr = this->head;
            }
            newNode->next = curr;
            prev->next = newNode;
            this->size++;
        }
    }catch(const std::exception& e){
        std::cerr << "caught exception " << e.what() << endl;
    }
}; //add at a specified index
```

I can add anything when I use add with index based

Comment: What is the signature of your `add` method?

Comment: It's clear that your method takes a `T`, and nothing else.  Please provide a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates it taking the wrong type.

Comment: can you show your node class, is it some kind of variant? or why can you construct it from any type?

Comment: Once you created list of Int all methods in the class replace T with int , List<int> l; now when you use l.add(); parameter will accept only integers. so you don't need to check inserted data.

Comment: "I can add anything". Show me.